# Is it possible to pass one argument to macro and get out two?

Tags: c++, macros

I'm trying to write some functions as macros, but I just can't figure it out how to do it.

```
#define PA0 (PORTA, PIN0_bm);
#define PA1 (PORTA, PIN1_bm);
...
#define PA7 (PORTA, PIN7_bm);

#define PD0 (PORTD, PIN0_bm);
#define PD1 (PORTD, PIN1_bm);
...
#define PD7 (PORTD, PIN7_bm);
```

then macro for function

```
#define pinMode(x)  (x[0].DIRSET = x[1])
```

which I wanted to look like after preprocessor

```
pinMode(PA0) -> (PORTA.DIRSET = PIN0_bm)
```

After compiling (AVR-gcc) I'm getting `invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript` error.

Is it possible to pass one argument to macro and get out two?

Comment: If you have the C++ language at your disposal, can you explain _why_ you are trying to solve this problem using macros?

Comment: Macros aren't methods.  `pinMode(PA0)` is 100% identical to `(PORTA,PIN0_bm);[0].DIRSET=(PORTA,PIN0_bm);[1])`, which obviously makes no sense

Comment: perhaps a `std::map` will do what you want.

Comment: Code will be running on time crucial application on microcontroller. For implementation in c++ this would be time consuming.

Comment: @JakobJug: Why not have the macros the other way around?  `#define pinmode(L,R) (L[0].DIRSET=R[1])` and then `#define PA0 pinmode(PORTA,PIN0_bm)` ?

Comment: @MooingDuck I understand. The way I wrote I can use PA0..PA7 macros for other functions with same argument like `#define digitalWrite(x) x[0].OUTSET = x[1]`

Comment: "...in c++ this would be time consuming."  When you measured, how much performance difference did you see?  I recommend you use c++ (because macros are discouraged) and prove to your self (and your peers and your boss) what you seem to believe.  Based on my experience for many years in embedded system, I discourage macros, mostly because -O3 is very good, and in-lining works.

Comment: @2785528 how I imagine implementation in C++, there would be many if or switch statements. I written a library in C to mimic this functionality and it is indeed time consuming. Especially on microcontroller with system clock less then 10MHz.

Comment: @JakobJug  and your C library (or macro library?) was how much faster than your imagined C++ code?  ... or perhaps, why are you submitting with the C++ tag?

Comment: `void pinMode(uint8_t pin) { switch (pin) { case PA0: PORTA.DIRSET = PINA; break; case PA1:....}` now repeat this case for all 96 pin's and now call function with case. I have a code which must read inputs on uC every 1ms and do bunch of stuff every 10ms. If you believe or not, the implentation of pinMode (and similar functions with other functions) was so time consuming that I couldn't read inputs at rate 1kHz.

Answer (score -1):

C++ macros end on the next newline, so the semicolons are being expanded, too. As originally suggested by [Mooing Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845092/mooing-duck):

> @JakobJug: Why not have the macros the other way around? `#define pinmode(L,R) (L[0].DIRSET=R[1])` and then `#define PA0 pinmode(PORTA,PIN0_bm)`?

Except it needs a small correction, giving `#define pinmode(L,R) (L.DIRSET=R)`. Then `PA0` expands to `pinmode(PORTA,PIN0_bm)` and then `(PORTA.DIRSET=PIN0_bm)`.

Comment: Pretty sure `{PORTA,PIN0_bm}[0].DIRSET={PORTA,PIN0_bm}[1])` is not what he needs either.

Comment: `{PORTA, PIN0_bm}` isn't an array and you can't subscript it.

Comment: @MooingDuck I mean yes, it does not do exactly what he wants, but I don't know that there is a way using macros to do exactly what he wants.

Comment: I'm dubious that `PIN0_bm` is of the same type as `PORTA`

Comment: `typeof` is a non poratable gcc extension and you still can cast a `{...}` to something, it doesn't have a type.

Comment: PIN0_bm and PORTA are not same types.

Comment: I would look at @MooingDuck's solution. I will edit my answer to reflect that (will give credit)

Comment: I do understand, but when `PA0` is defined as `(PORTA, PIN0_bm)` I could use it for different function like `#define digitalWrite(x) x[0].OUTSET = x[1]` and also use the same argument `digitalWrite(PA0);`. If this is not the case then I might just define function like `#define pinMode(PORTx, PINx) (PORTx.DIRSET = PINx)` and call it like `pinMode(PORTA, PIN0_bm);`. Appreciate your help!